# ERC20 token transfer to another address

Tags: solidity

I am currently learning solidity and I have created a smart contract that can handle transfer of ERC-20 token from one address to another. But I have encountered a problem wherein the token is being transferred to the contract address instead of the wallet address.

Please see code below

```
        require(msg.value >= transactionDetails.converted_amount);
        transactionDetails.token.transfer(payable(wallet_address), transactionDetails.converted_amount);
        transactions[transactionID] = transactionDetails;
        transaction_list.push(transactionID);
```

Comment: Please share more code, it's not possible to identify the problem with this part of code only